# Checking if a string contains a particular substring in Velocity

Tags: java, string, substring, velocity

In Velocity I have a variable called $url which contains the following string:  [ContentId(2.7507), ContentId(2.7508), ContentId(1.44551)]

I want to check if that string contains the substring 1.44551.

This is the code I've written so far, but for some reason it's returning False:

```
#if($url.contains("1.44551"))
<p>The article content id is 1.44551</p>
#else
<p>The article content id isn't 1.44551</p>
#end
```

I would expect this to be returning True, as the 1.44551 substring is present in the $url variable.  Please can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Looks fine at first glance.  If you write your test as `#if(true)` or `#if($url.equals($url))`: does it return True then?  I guess what I'm getting at is, make sure that Velocity is evaluating the expression.

Comment: oops, the same thing was happening for me (but I realised the object I was trying to use contains on wasn't a String!)... once I called toString first it was fine i.e. `messageQuery.message.JMSDestination.toString().contains("DLQ")`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Velocity holds values as **Objects** in context map.

If you want to execute String method, add `toString` to make sure you execute on String the `contains` method:

```
 #if($url.toString().contains("1.44551"))
<p>The article content id is 1.44551</p>
#else
<p>The article content id isn't 1.44551</p>
#end
```