# Velocity Template Language: Connect two conditions in one #elseif() statement

Tags: if-statement, velocity, polarion, velocity-template-language

In my example the parameters are:

**$p2.length**

which has the value "**0**"

and the boolean

**$suspectYesNo** which is set to "**false**".

I would expect, that in my code the **second #elseif** will run due to my set parameters, but however it shows up that "Code 4 runs"

I guess, that my mistake is the connection of both conditions using "**&&**", but I have no clue how to correctly define the line with two conditions.

That brings me to the question: How to correctly combine the two conditions ($p2.length()==0) AND ($suspectYesNo.value.contains("true")) in one #elseif().

Or did I define the boolean wrong?

```
  #if($p2.length()>0)

  Code 1 runs

  #elseif($p2.length()==0 && $suspectYesNo.value.contains("true"))

  Code 2 runs

  #elseif($p2.length()==0 && $suspectYesNo.value.contains("false"))

  Code 3 runs

  #else

  Code 4 runs

  #end
```

Comment: Are you sure you have to call length() like a function ? shouldn't you check on `$p2.length === 0` instead of `$p2.length() == 0` ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229377/checking-if-a-string-contains-a-particular-substring-in-velocity

Comment: @Dinosan0908: Thanks for your hint. I've corrected those parts to: 
$p2.length == 0
(With "===" it didn't work - However it did not really change anything in the behaviour)

Comment: @user7294900: Thanks! With your reference I made it working. I post my solution!

Comment: @user7294900: Done :) Thank you very much!

Comment: @SteffPoint You welcome, I meant my answer in the link

Comment: @user7294900: Sorry, my bad :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to user7294900 for providing me a reference with which I could solve the problem.

It did not read the boolean value as a string, which could be fixed by adding "toString()" method.

With this code here it works as desired:

```
  #if($p2.length > 0)

  Code 1 runs

  #elseif($p2.length == 0 && $suspectYesNo.value.toString().contains("true"))

  Code 2 runs

  #elseif($p2.length == 0 && $suspectYesNo.value.toString().contains("false"))

  Code 3 runs

  #else

  Code 4 runs

  #end
```